# Is there an idiomatic expression for "look at things from the other person's perspective"?

Tags: idiom-request

I am writing a small essay wherein I want to urge the reader to "look at his problem from the other person's perspective" (to understand why the other person is behaving in a particular way).

Example: (just making this up, not from my actual essay, which is somewhat ... uhm, confidential)

> **Jane**: My husband is always late from work, and he even works weekends. He never seems to have time for me. 
>   **Friend**: I have sympathies for you. However, try *looking at this from his perspective*. Well paying jobs are hard to come by, and he needs the overtime to build a good future for your family.

Is there a more "flowery" or idiomatic expression I could use to replace the italicized phrase?

I used to occasionally use [put the boot on the other foot](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+boot+is+on+the+other+foot), but I recently realized that it doesn't mean what I thought it meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Looking at this from his perspective* sounds good to me. You could also say

- putting yourself in his position
- looking at it through his eyes.

If you really want an  idiom, in addition to *putting yourself in his shoes*, you could try *walking a mile in his shoes*:

> [walk a mile in (someone's) shoes](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/walk+a+mile+in+her+shoes)
>   To spend time trying to consider or understand another person's perspectives, experiences, or motivations before making a judgment about them. *I know that certain people can come across as selfish or mean-spirited, but you should try walking a mile in their shoes before you dismiss them too quickly.*

Answer (score 1):

[**put oneself in someone's shoes**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+someone's+shoes) or [**in someone's place**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+someone's+shoes) are the only expressions that come to my mind.

Comment: Are they formal expressions ? Can they be used in academic writing ?